# How to limit trigger loops?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, stack

I wrote a trigger that update a new row in the same table.

l

When I update the fist row, my trigger tries to update all the relevant rows and I get an error "stack depth limit exceeded"

To increase this mimit is not a solution since my table will be bigger and bigger.

But I never need to update from the first rows the best solution is to limit the maximun of "loops" the trigger can do.

I don't know how to have a "loop counter" and I don't find any way to retrieve the real stack usage that should be another solution.

Any idea regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pg_trigger_depth(), but I strongly suggest not to and review DB design.

For documentation about function see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html

I quote:

> " pg_trigger_depth () → integer
>
> Returns the current nesting level of PostgreSQL triggers (0 if not
> called, directly or indirectly, from inside a trigger)."

Why is it bad? Not to repeat what other people wrote, I suggest to read the answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163142/is-pg-trigger-depth-bad-to-use-for-preventing-trigger-cascading-recursion

Comment: Thans for your answer I did not know pg_trigger_depth and I should say it's not always bad but it's another thread.